# Dynamic Paypal button based on email account address

Tags: php, paypal

Is there a way to modify the PAYPAL generated button code below to make it dynamic using a php varible? This is the original code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZBA2RX3Q8L9V8">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This is the logic that I am after:

```
<?PHP $paypal_email=client@website.com; ?>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="<?PHP echo $paypal_email ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

THIS IS MORE DYNAMIC-FRIENDLY AND IT WORKED:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/ck/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?PHP ech VARIABLE HERE; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: I think the following PAYPAL generated code is more dynamic-friendly:

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS MORE DYNAMIC-FRIENDLY AND IT WORKED:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/ck/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?PHP ech VARIABLE HERE; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="ITEM NAME">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```